# How to run a Simes test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, multiple-comparisons, simulation, bonferroni

I'm looking to set up a Simes test in R. I'm trying to show that a Simes test is conservative with when a positive correlation exists.

I know how correct the p-values using the p.adjust function, but I am looking to set up a simulation under the following conditions:

1.) Multivariate $\mathcal{N}$(0,1) distribution.

2.) $\alpha$ = .05

3.) number of k tests = 2, 20, and 100

4.) $\rho$ = 0, 0.5, and 0.9

I have this code as a reference to use:

```
library(MASS)
alpha <- .05
m <- 20
n.sim <- 10000
n.Rejection <- rep(0,n.sim)
rho<- 0
mu <- rep(0,m)
Sigma <- matrix(rho,m,m)
diag(Sigma) <- 1
for (i in 1:n.sim)
{
z <- rnorm(m)
z <- mvrnorm(1,mu,Sigma)
p <- pnorm(z)
n.Rejection[i] <- length(p[p<=alpha])
}
```